# create array with data from different request in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

here is my code, first of all, i made a first request :

```
        $scope.displayuser = function(id){
            var token = "xxxxx";
            userdisplay
                .send(token,id)
                .then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.userbyorga = data.users;
                    $scope.numtickets = [];
                    for(i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
                        var userid = data.users;
                        $scope.numtickets[userid.id] = {nbuser:data.users[i].name};
                        var userarray = JSON.stringify(userid);
                        localStorage.setItem("myid",userarray);
                    }
                    console.log($scope.numtickets);
                })
```

what we have to remember is that : 
 `$scope.numtickets[userid.id] = {nbuser:data.users[i].name};`
I'm pushing in my array the name of my user and keep the id of the user

then i made a second request here in keeping with the code i just showed you:

```
                .then(function(){
                    var tabuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myid"));
                    console.log(tabuser);
                    var urls = [];

                    for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
                        urls.push({
                            url:JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+tabuser[i].id+"/tickets/requested.json")
                        });

                        console.log(tabuser[i].id);
                        console.log($scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]);
                        displayfilter
                            .user(token,tabuser[i].id)
                            .then(function(data){

                                $scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length;
                                console.log($scope.numtickets);
                                console.log(data.tickets.length);

                            })
                        console.log(tabuser[i]);
                    }
                })

        };
```

And what we need to remember here is this:

```
 $scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length;
```

i'm pushing the number of tickets and associate with the same array i used for my user.

My issue :

is on this line:

```
$scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length;
```

"$scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id] is not defined."
 So it' s not working . can someone could help me pls ?

i would like something like this at the end :

```
{
     1: {
        'nbuser': 'User name1',
        'nbticket': '1',
      },
     2: {
        'nbuser': 'User name2',
        'nbticket': '2',
     }
     3: {
       'nbuser': 'User name3',
       'nbticket': '2',
      }
}
```

and then it would be easy to display this in my view like :

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in numtickets track by $index">
        <li>{{user.nbuser}}</li>
        <li>{{user.nbticket}}</li>
</ul>


console.log($scope.numtickets[userid.id]);
```

[image]

here is all the json for data.users:
[image]

Comment: Could you show the value of userid.id?

Comment: Is that the content form the data.users? I am asking for the id property of the users.

Comment: Great, can you now display the content of tabuser[i].id?

Comment: hey, first of all thanks for trying to help me, and just to make sure, the problem is from this lane `$scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length;` you just rewrite what i did in my first request :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110153/discussion-between-jordi-ruiz-and-guillaume-nouhaud).

Comment: try `console.log()` all the values of `$scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket']` it will help you see if there is any data or there are just positions that are undefined, because they got "no data"

Comment: Guilleame, the problem that I can see is that maybe there is not an element in the position of the array that you are looking at when you do something like: $scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id], this is why I would like you to show the value for tabuser[i].id

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
      var currentI = i;
      displayfilter
           .user(token,tabuser[i].id)
             .then(function(data){
              $scope.numtickets[tabuser[currentI].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length;
     })
 }
```

So what did i do ? I stored the `i` in a local `currentI` variable of the `for`. This should work because each currentI variable will be local to the callback of the `then`function otherwise your i will have the value of `tabuser.length`. This is because of `closure`. On each iteration of your for you will recreate a new callback function for the then. However they will have the same closures. The only closure's level they won't have in common will be every variable declared in the for loop.

You might want take a look to `$q.all` too you can group promise and process them all together making thing simplier.

Note : is this a duplicate ? I was sure to have already answer this not so long ago ...